# How to remove the 0-s form the array so that the array doesn't look like 0 0 3 0 5 for example but instead looks like 3 5

Tags: c

Im  a beginner programmer and i needed some help with making the result of the following exercise look a bit better.
As i said in the title i want to make the exercise look nicer by removing the 0-s from the array and leaving just the numbers.

The exercise goes like this:

We enter an array of integers and we copy into the 2nd array the integers that are positive and negative and multiples of 3 and in the 3rd array the negative elements that are odd and not multiples of 3. This is the code that I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5
int main()
{
    int v[N];
    int v2[N] = {0, };
    int v3[N] = {0, };
    int i;
    printf("Please enter the elements of the 1st array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe elements of the 2nd array are: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if ((v[i] >= 0 || v[i] <= 0) && v[i] % 3 == 0)
        {
            v2[i] = v[i];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v2[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe value of the 3rd array are : ");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] <= 0 && v[i] % 2 != 0 && v[i] % 3 != 0)
        {
            v3[i] = v[i];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", v3[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For future use if possible how to do I post a code copied for code blocks directly into here without using space 4 times on every line?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As you can see from my edit, I have surrounded your code block by four subsequent backticks or accent graves.

Comment: `int a = atoi("000123");` will produce an integer value of `123`.

Comment: On the source formatting: Use a good editor that helps you indent your code properly, optimally automating it. Choose spaces instead of tabs, 4 is a common number. Choose a common code style and stick to it. Don't format by hand, but in rare cases. Only then copy the source into the question.

Comment: @ryyker, i dont think that this is what he wants...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to insert a condition in the output loop:

```c
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (v2[i] != 0)
    {
        printf("%d ",v2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer to his question, but it ommits the - not stated - fact, that 0 are ignored as input...